# Conditionals & Control Flow - The Big If

Tags: python

Very simple! Where did I get this wrong? I typed 5 and it returned false... What did I miss?

```
# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True
def the_flying_circus():
    print "Press number 5 otherwise it will return false"
    a = raw_input()
    if a == 5:
        print "Correct!"
        return True
        # Start coding here!
        # Don't forget to indent
        # the code inside this block!
    elif a != 5:
        print "Wrong"
        return False
        # Keep going here.
        # You'll want to add the else statement, too!
    else:
        return False
the_flying_circus()
print "Thank you for playing!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert your `raw_input` to an `int`.

`raw_input()` always returns a `string`

do `a = int(raw_input())`

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input` always returns a string. "5" does not equal 5.